# Python: Making changes to key-value of List of list

Tags: python, json, list

Im sending input payload from Postman to my Flask service like this:

```
{
    "input": [
        [{
            "name": "IP 2.0",
            "rebootRequired": "default"
        },
        {
            "name": "IP 3.0",
            "rebootRequired": "Yes"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Reading data in Flask service:

```
data = request.get_json()
input = data['input']
```

I want to make changes to input variable so that my final list of list becomes like this. So I want to rename "name" key to "packageId" and remove other key-values like rebootRequired.

```
[
        [{
            "packageId": "IP 2.0"
        },
        {
            "packageId": "IP 3.0"
        }]
]
```

How should I go about it. Tried some tricks but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Share an attempt you expected to work and explain what the problem was. A very straightforward approach would be a list comprehension that just creates new dictionaries with only the `'packageId'` key, using the `'name'` value for each dictionary in the old list

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and reconstruct another list of dict, from the existing ones.

One approach will be like this

```
__input = data['input']
modified_input = [[dict(packageId=pack) for pack in package] for package in [[d.get("name") for d in inp] for inp in __input]]
print(modified_input)
```

## Output

```
[[{'packageId': 'IP 2.0'}, {'packageId': 'IP 3.0'}]]
```

There could be more optimal ways to do it, but this is the gist of it.